# How do I get an iPhone App to pull information from the Web?

Tags: iphone, ios, rss, xcode4.3

I'm new to some of App Development and was wondering the following;

How can I get an app to pull information from the web into it? For example I want to have a "More" tab on the bottom of my app. Within this "More" tab, a tableview opens and I want it to pull from the web. I will be inputting links to my other apps into it to cross market. I've seen this done in another app named "Emoji.." (The app with the heart wearing shades in the Icon by Empire Apps). Essentially I would like it to pull from (i guess) a webpage I create that would have the links along with the icon image in it. Unfortunately the best way I can describe it. It would be almost like the one from that emoji app I spoke about prior. Once again I'm new and English is not my first language so I apologize if I'm not clear enough. I have no idea however how to get this accomplished both in the Xcode side, nor on the web side. Any advice is GREATLY appreciated and I thank you all in advance for your time!

Comment: Vague.  Is this info hosted on a server?  Are you parsing a feed?  Do you need a POST request?  Etc.

Comment: yeah it's vague, but he did mention that he/she is new to some app development. So your comment will help him realize that there are many ways to get information from the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your application display a webpage, try this code on your app delegate for example.
You can make a webpage and display your links and other information there, and when a user presses "more" on your app, make your app display the web page on a window/view on the application itself

Maybe this is what you want to achieve?

anyway, there are many ways to pull information from the web(or a server) like POST, etc.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc]
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];

    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.window addSubview:webView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys! Didn't realize I was being too vague, I apologize. Essentially I would like it to pull from (i guess) a webpage I create that would have the links along with the icon image in it. Unfortunately the best way I can describe it. It would be almost like the one from that emoji app I spoke about prior. Once again I'm new and English is not my first language so I apologize if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: probably the comment you posted here is more suited to be posted on the comments on your question rather than here in my answer. Anyway, if you notice, my answer is how you can display a webpage on your app, like what you just mentioned that you wanted. I hope it helps